# Improper output coming from textbox while using SendKeys to send data in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, sendkeys

I am developing a winForm application which is sending values to textbox of different app(java application) using sendkeys.

below is my code

```
    SendKeys.Send("abcd".ToUpper().Trim());
    Thread.Sleep(50);
    //it will send tab key to focus next textbox
    SendKeys.Send("{TAB}");
    Thread.Sleep(50);
    SendKeys.Send("efgh".ToUpper().Trim());
    //send tab to get focus on button
    SendKeys.Send("{TAB}");
    // it will send key "Enter" for mouse click
    SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}");
```

but sendKeys are sending wrong data to textboxes.
desire output should be **abcd** to **textbox1** and **efgh** to **textbox2**. but sometimes i am getting **abcde** to **texbox1** and **fgh** to **textbox2**. its merging the input values.
is anyone having an idea why this is happening?
Please let me know how i can fix this.

Comment: i am **sending** values to third party java Application.can you plz share some code how i can send value to textbox (java App) from my winForm Application.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure `TabIndex` property is properly configured. For Example [image: App]
2. On **Send Key**  button [TabIndex : 0] is clicked i have added a Tab to navigate the focus to next `control`[focus to `TextBox1`] in the `form` then did what you are trying to achieve.

   ```
   private void btnSendKey_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       SendKeys.Send("{TAB}");
       Thread.Sleep(50);

       SendKeys.Send("abcd".ToUpper().Trim());
       Thread.Sleep(50);
       //it will send tab key to focus next textbox
       SendKeys.Send("{TAB}");
       Thread.Sleep(50);
       SendKeys.Send("efgh".ToUpper().Trim());
       //send tab to get focus on button
       SendKeys.Send("{TAB}");
       // it will send key "Enter" for mouse click
       SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}");
   }
   ```

On **Enter Key** click just displaying the Value

```
    private void btnEnter_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Text Box 1: " + textBox1.Text.ToString() + " - Text Box 2:" + textBox2.Text.ToString());
    }`
```

Comment: thanks for your reply but i am trying to send data to another applications textbox and one more thing try to click continuously on **Sendkey button** you will also get same error like i am getting